# Starting a subsystem process with sshd on a constrained embedded system

Tags: embedded-linux, openssh, sshd, ietf-netconf, dropbear

I am trying to get the `yuma123` open source implementation of a NETCONF Server running on an embedded Linux system.

The NETCONF Server uses `sshd`, and `yuma123` appears to assume that it is the `openssh` implementation of `sshd` as it uses the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

In particular, the `README` file in `yuma123` states:

```
Tell sshd to listen on port 830. Add the following 2 lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

Port 830
Subsystem netconf "/usr/sbin/netconf-subsystem --ncxserversockname=830@/tmp/ncxserver.sock"
```

However, the embedded system currently uses the `dropbear` cut-down implementation of `sshd` due to memory constraints, and I am having difficulty getting `openssh` (together at the same time with `yuma123`) installed on the embedded system due to the size of the executables, dependant libraries etc.

Can I get/amend the `dropbear` `sshd` to give me similar functionality? Can I cut-down the `openssh` `sshd` drastically to a small enough size? Any (other) suggestions on a good way forward to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [dropbear source code](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear), the only subsystem built into the dropbear SSH server is optional support for SFTP, which I'll describe below.

Supporting another subsystem requires making source code changes to dropbear. If that's an option, the code at issue is in the function [`sessioncommand()` in the file `svr-chansession.c`](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blob/DROPBEAR_2018.76/svr-chansession.c#L665):

```
#if DROPBEAR_SFTPSERVER
            if ((cmdlen == 4) && strncmp(chansess->cmd, "sftp", 4) == 0) {
                m_free(chansess->cmd);
                chansess->cmd = m_strdup(SFTPSERVER_PATH);
            } else 
#endif
            {
                m_free(chansess->cmd);
                return DROPBEAR_FAILURE;
            }
```

Basically, you'd add some code similar to the "sftp" section which checks for your subsystem name and invokes the desired command.

If you don't want to build a custom version of dropbear, then you might be able to make do with a forced command. There are two ways to do this.

If the users of this subsystem will be authenticating with an SSH key, then you could put a "command" directive in the user's `authorized_keys` file:

```
command="/usr/sbin/netconf-subsystem..." ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When a client authenticates with the key from this line in the file, then any command, shell or subsystem request from the client will cause dropbear to invoke the listed command instead of the command requested by the client. This is an OpenSSH server feature that's also supported by dropbear.

Alternately, dropbear has a command-line option `-c` which lets you specify a forced command for all clients:

```
dropbear -p 830 ... -c '/usr/sbin/netconf-subsystem ...'
```

Dropbear will invoke the specified command for any client connecting to this dropbear instance. If you want to permit clients to do other things besides running that command, you'd have to run two instances of dropbear, listening on different ports or addresses.

### SFTP Subsystem support:

I'll describe this because doesn't seem to be well documented. 
If dropbear is [compiled with the option `DROPBEAR_SFTPSERVER`](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blob/DROPBEAR_2018.76/default_options.h#L249), then dropbear will invoke the command "/usr/libexec/sftp-server" for clients requesting the "sftp" subsystem. For that to work, the administrator would normally build a copy of the [OpenSSH sftp-server](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server) program from the OpenSSH source code, and install the resulting program as `/usr/libexec/sftp-server`.

Changing dropbear to run a different command requires altering the dropbear source code and recompiling dropbear.

Comment: I used `dropbear` with the `-c` option to start the subsystem, as suggested by @Kenster. This allows me to connect to the `yuma123` NETCONF Server using OpenSSH's `ssh localhost -p 830` and start a NETCONF session, i.e. the NETCONF Server provides me with a session ID in the `<hello>` tag element. However,  attempting to connect using `yuma123`'s `yangcli` NETCONF Client results in the session terminating immediately. Is there a difference between `ssh` and `yangcli` as a NETCONF Client? There was no problem using `yangcli` when the NETCONF Server used OpenSSH's `sshd` for a NETCONF session.

Comment: Since my last comment, I have now managed to get the `yangcli` connection working by applying @Kenster's suggested code change. `yangcli` specifies `netconf` as the subsystem name, and this has to be matched up with the `netconf-subsystem` executable (plus the correct arguments, such as `--ncxserversockname=830@/tmp/ncxserver.sock`). When the subsystem is executed, the input/output is set up between the NETCONF Client and the NETCONF Server, providing a secure channel for the NETCONF session. Obviously, the `ssh` and `sftp` clients use their own SSH and SFTP server subsystems respectively.